# How to pull out ids in R that are interlinked?

Tags: r, relationship

I have two columns id1 and id2 which have interconnected list of id's. I am looking for a solution in R that can pull those id's together based on their relationship. The basic idea is that the id's 313-320 are all interlinked, e.g. 313 linked to 314 (row1) and because 314 is linked to 316 (row 7) so 313 and 316 are also linked and so on. The solution somehow has to explore these linkages and put them together in a chain such that 313-320 will be in one and 321-328 will be in a second one.

```
id1<-c(313,313,313,313,313,314,314,314,314,315,317,317,317,318,318,319,321,321,321,321,321,321,321,322,322,322,322,322, 322,323,323,323,323,323,324,324,324,324,325,325,325,326,326,327)

id2<-c(314,315,316,319,320,315,316,319,320,316,318,319,320,319,320,320,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,323,324,325,326,327, 328,324,325,326,327,328,325,326,327,328,326,327,328,327,328,328)

df<-cbind.data.frame(id1, id2)

> df
   id1 id2
1  313 314
2  313 315
3  313 316
4  313 319
5  313 320
6  314 315
7  314 316
8  314 319
9  314 320
10 315 316
11 317 318
12 317 319
13 317 320
14 318 319
15 318 320
16 319 320
17 321 322
18 321 323
19 321 324
20 321 325
21 321 326
22 321 327
23 321 328
24 322 323
25 322 324
26 322 325
27 322 326
28 322 327
29 322 328
30 323 324
31 323 325
32 323 326
33 323 327
34 323 328
35 324 325
36 324 326
37 324 327
38 324 328
39 325 326
40 325 327
41 325 328
42 326 327
43 326 328
44 327 328
```

Greatly appreciate an input here how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
id1<-c(313,313,313,313,313,314,314,314,314,315,317,317,317,318,318,319,321,321,321,321,321,321,321,322,322,322,322,322, 322,323,323,323,323,323,324,324,324,324,325,325,325,326,326,327)

id2<-c(314,315,316,319,320,315,316,319,320,316,318,319,320,319,320,320,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,323,324,325,326,327, 328,324,325,326,327,328,325,326,327,328,326,327,328,327,328,328)

df<-cbind.data.frame(id1, id2)
```

This is a bit messy, but it works. You just set which rows are to be grouped (here 1 - 16 and then 17-44)

```
df<-data.frame(row1=unlist(df[1:16,])[which(!duplicated(unlist(df[1:16,])))],
row2=unlist(df[17:44,])[which(!duplicated(unlist(df[17:44,])))]
)
```

As two different columns:

```
df
          row1 row2
id11   313  321
id16   314  322
id110  315  323
id111  317  324
id114  318  325
id116  319  326
id23   316  327
id25   320  328
```

Or as two rows, as you specified:

```
t(df)
     id11 id16 id110 id111 id114 id116 id23 id25
row1  313  314   315   317   318   319  316  320
row2  321  322   323   324   325   326  327  328
```

---

### Edit:

since you are looking for an answer where you can select the range of values, something like this would work:

```
id1<-c(313,313,313,313,313,314,314,314,314,315,317,317,317,318,318,319,321,321,321,321,321,321,321,322,322,322,322,322, 322,323,323,323,323,323,324,324,324,324,325,325,325,326,326,327)

id2<-c(314,315,316,319,320,315,316,319,320,316,318,319,320,319,320,320,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,323,324,325,326,327, 328,324,325,326,327,328,325,326,327,328,326,327,328,327,328,328)

df<-cbind.data.frame(id1, id2)



df2<-unlist(df)[which(!duplicated(unlist(df)))]

rows1<-c(313:320)
rows2<-c(321:328)


df3<-data.frame(row1=df2[which(df2%in%rows1)],
               row2=df2[which(df2%in%rows2)]
)
df3

> df3
      row1 row2
id11   313  321
id16   314  322
id110  315  323
id111  317  324
id114  318  325
id116  319  326
id23   316  327
id25   320  328
```

Comment: I think the issue here is really that I don't even know which rows can be grouped, it is just an example so I specified grouping to explain but in the real data I have no such clue. The solution somehow needs to based on the linkages without really specifying the grouping so that all the numbers in the data that are connected can be pulled together and grouped in individual rows.

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? I can edit my answer to include that as well if you have not.

Comment: That would be great. I still haven't figured out the best way to do it.

Comment: Is this now closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: This solution is close to what I am looking for but still not what I want. The reason is that I don't know which rows could be grouped together. Imagine having the id pairs in row 1 and 2 distributed randomly where I don't have the grouping info, how would that work then. The idea is that the id's 313-320 are linked like in a chain, e.g. 313 linked to 314 (row1) and because 314 is linked to 316 (row 7) so 313 and 316 are linked and  so on. The solution somehow has to explore these linkages and put them together like in chain.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include this information. It currently lacks the detail necessary to know that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question and have included the necessary details.